# Es posible crear una respuesta de JSON en angular

Tags: json, angular

Necesito generar una respuesta a una ruta en angular, pero esta me debe generar un JSON para que la lea una api luego de llamar una URL

Por ejemplo:

mi.angular/mi-ruta

yo con eso proceso y debo retornar un json solamente

Muchas gracias.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++

Actualización e información adicional.

Soy nuevo en Angular, vengo de PHP con symfony. Siendo más exacto necesito hacer lo siguiente:

Estoy armando una aplicación en Angular 5+, entonces recibo una petición (Request) por GET en una URI a través del Router de Angular.

En mi Router de Angular redirecciono hacia mi componente.

Quiero que mi Componente me resuelva la petición (el request) generando una respuesta (Response) código 200 (status code), que no renderice text/html sino que genere application/json (Content-Type).

Espero que sea un poco más clara mi inquietud, he buscado mucho y no encuentro la forma de solucionarlo en Angular, lo que me lleva a preguntar si es posible, y agradezco si es posible alguna referencia de por dónde comenzar.

Mil gracias.

Comment: Creo que te falta expandir un poco mas lo que necesitas, que versión de angular usas angular 4 o angular js y que lenguaje de servidor manejas.

Comment: Creo que te falta expandir un poco mas lo que necesitas, que versión de angular usas angular 4 o angular js y que lenguaje de servidor manejas.

Comment: Hola. Uso Angular 5. Tengo una aplicacion con el router funcionando, y funciona bien, pero necesito que al seleccionar un route la petición de respuesta sea un json

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. ¿Podrías explicar mejor el problema? Así mismo, coloca lo que has intentado.

Comment: Hola @Gabriel, debes brindar mayor información para poderte ayudar. Lo que dices en tu pregunta es muy abierta y hasta dificil de comprender. Lo que he entendido, ya me corriges si estoy en lo correcto o no, es que pretendes realizar una petición (CRUD) a una API en formato JSON?

Comment: Gracias a todos por responderme. Soy nuevo en Angular, vengo de PHP con symfony.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mockearte una respuesta.

**mockear, es hacer una respuesta fake. Esta respuesta tiene la misma estructura que te devuelve el servidor al que ira conectado el servicio.**

Metes la respuesta en una constante. La estructura será la misma que la que te devolverá el servidor

constants.ts

```
export const USER = { 
   'name':"pepe",
   'surname': "Martin",
}
```

Llamas al servicio desde tu componente

```
public user: User;
constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.userService.me().subscribe((user: User) => {
         this.user = user;
   });
}
```

El servicio en vez de llamar al endpoint del servidor, responde el usuario que tenemos en constants.ts

userService.ts

```
import { USER } from './constants.ts';
public me(): Observable<User> {
    return Observable.of(USER);
 }
```

Con esto mockerias un servicio y puedes probar tu front, sin tener un servidor funcionando.

saludos

Comment: esto no es una respuesta sino un comentario extendido, que no debería ir en esta zona, por favor eliminalo o mejoralo

Comment: Enrique genial, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Lo intenté aunque aún no me funciona. Te sigo contando a ver cómo lo soluciono, por el momento me monté un servidor de nodejs y generé con express el json en una ruta. MIl gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: Es importante revisar [answer]

Comment: de nada @gabrielrincon